# Android buttons showing up invisible

Tags: android, xml

So i created a circle.xml file and used it as a background for buttons and now the buttons dont show up when rendered on a device screen, their text still shows up for the shape doesnt.

circle.xml code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring">
    <solid android:color="#a03123"/>
</shape>
```

Layout code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backgroundii"
    tools:context="com.example.trucktracker.Locator"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/updatebtn"
        android:onClick="clickedUpdate"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="@string/updatenow"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/togglelocationupdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:textOff="Automatic Updates Off"
        android:textOn="Automatic Updates On" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deliver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delivery"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/updatebtn"
        android:layout_below="@+id/splitPOinput"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/updatebtn"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/contactbtn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:onClick="clickedContact"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:text="@string/contactcompany"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_below="@+id/updatebtn"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latitudetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/latitude"
        tools:context=".Locator"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logitudetext"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textLong" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logitudetext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/longitude"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/POnumber"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/togglelocationupdate"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/contactbtn"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/contactbtn" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textLat"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logitudetext" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textLat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textLong"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/latitudetext"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/POnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ponumber"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/updatebtn"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/splitPOtitle"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/splitPOtitle" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/optionselecti"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/question"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/question" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="9dp"
        android:text="@string/question1"
        android:textSize="19sp"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/POnumber"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/POnumber" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/addressfromserver"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/splitPOtitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/deliver"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/question"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/question" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/POinput"
        android:layout_below="@+id/POnumber" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/splitPO"
        android:id="@+id/splitPOtitle"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/POinput"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/deliver"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/deliver"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/splitPOinput"
        android:layout_below="@+id/splitPOtitle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post your complete layout pls

Comment: @deniz layout posted

Comment: is backgroundii also a drawable shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set android:thickness="20dp" tag inside shape

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:thickness="20dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid android:color="#FF0000"/>
 </shape>
```